# untar all files in specific directory but not the directory

Tags: linux, tar

I think this may be a simple question but cannot find the answer.

I am trying to extract some files from a tar file. These files are in a directory within the tar file. I tried the following however this didnt work

```
tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz folder/*
```

I thought this would simply extract all the files in the directory but not the directory itself. The only way I think I could do it currently would be something like this.

```
tar -zxvf filename.tar.gz folder
mv folder/* ../
rm folder
```

Hopefully there is a more efficient method to complete this  task. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU tar, you can use **--strip-components** option which strips a specified number of  leading components from file names before extraction:

```
tar zxfv filename.tar.gz --strip-components=1
tar zxfv filename.tar.gz folder/ --strip-components=1
```

Comment: Never would of guessed that. Works perfectly. Thank you :)